# How to interpret moreover and a series like Y1,. . . ,Yn in prolog program

Tags: prolog

For my exercise I have this program. Consider the following Prolog program, which realizes simple terms built from variables and the function symbol `plus`.

```
variable(x).
variable(y).
term(X) :- variable(X).
term(plus(X,Y)):- term(X), term(Y).
```

a) Implement a predicate `uses(TERM, A)` in Prolog which is true iff `TERM` is a term built with `plus` and `A` is an argument of the outermost `plus` symbol of `TERM`, i.e., `term(TERM)` is true and, moreover, `TERM = plus(A,_)` or `TERM = plus(_,A).`

b) Implement a predicate `contains(TERM, X)` in Prolog which is true iff `TERM` is a term built with `plus` and `X` is a subterm of `TERM`. In other words, `contains(TERM, X)` is true iff `uses(TERM, X)` is true or if
there are `n > 0` elements `Y1,. . . ,Yn` such that the following statements are true:

```
• uses(TERM,Y1)
• uses(Yn,X)
• uses(Yi−1,Yi) for all i ∈ {2, . . . , n}.
```

Make sure that the evaluation of all queries `?- contains(t1,t2)` terminates if `t1` and `t2` are ground terms.

So far I have come up with the following solutions:

a) `uses(TERM, A) :- term(TERM), (TERM=plus(A,_); TERM=plus(_,A)).`

I am confused here whether this solution is correct. In the question they used "moreover" and for this I kept `TERM` in first bracket like this `(TERM=plus(A,_); TERM=plus(_,A))`. Is this correct?

b)

```
contains(TERM, X) :- uses(TERM, X).
contains(TERM, X) :- uses(TERM, I), contains(I,X).
```

well I am confused here whether my answer is correct or not. I don't know how to interpret a series like `Y1,. . . ,Yn` in Prolog.

Comment: *moreover* just means *in addition* or *also*, perhaps adding emphasis but a little redundant in this context. Your interpretation of (a) appears correct. In (b), `Y1, ..., Yn` could be just a list of `n` elements. What `n` is doesn't matter specifically. The rules of the problem use `n` as a way to indicate that it's an enumerable list.